# Overriding variables with included roles and OS specific tasks - normal Ansible behavior?

Tags: ansible

I have a question about the following situation:

role_a:

```
role_a/
├── defaults
├── tasks
│   ├── main.yml
│   ├── RedHat.yml
│   └── Ubuntu.yml
└── vars
    ├── RedHat.yml
    └── Ubuntu.yml

role_b/
├── defaults
├── tasks
│   ├── main.yml
│   ├── RedHat.yml
│   └── Ubuntu.yml
└── vars
    ├── RedHat.yml
    └── Ubuntu.yml
```

Basic example, the main.yml contains the following code:

```
---
- name: gather os specific variables
  ansible.builtin.include_vars: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.first_found', params) }}"
  vars:
    params:
      files:
        - "{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.yml"
        - "{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
      paths:
        - 'vars'

- name: include os specific tasks
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.first_found', params) }}"
  vars:
    params:
      files:      
        - "{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.yml"
        - "{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
      paths:
        - 'tasks'
```

In the first situation, role_a includes role_b (e.g. in the tasks/Debian.yml file):

```
---
- name: Include role b
  include_role:
    name: role_b

- name: Print a message
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: Role_a finished!
```

The following playbook applies role_a:

```
---
- hosts: test
  remote_user: root
  vars:
  roles:
    - role_a
```

..and the following error occurs:

```
PLAY [test] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test-server]

TASK [role_a : gather os specific variables] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test-server]

TASK [role_a : include os specific tasks] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
included: /home/user/test/roles/role_a/tasks/Ubuntu.yml for test-server

TASK [Include role b] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [role_b : gather os specific variables] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [test-server]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "ansible_included_var_files": [], "changed": false, "message": "/home/user/test/roles/role_b/tasks/Ubuntu.yml must be stored as a dictionary/hash"}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
test-server    : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The error: role_b gets included by role_a and the main.yml of role_b tries to include the tasks/Ubuntu.yml where it should include the vars/Ubuntu.yml of role_b.

This doesn't happen when I include role_b with:

role_a/meta/main.yml:

```
---
dependencies:
  - { role: role_b }
```

..instead of the include_role command.

Or: when each 'params' variable has a different name (params_role_a_vars, params_role_a_tasks, params_role_b_vars, etc) the script runs fine.

I understand that it has to do with variable overriding, still I find it strange behavior. Can someone explain? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

(See solution at the end of this message)

The problem described in this question is normal Ansible behavior. When including something, the interpreter will look first in other roles before searching for the next file name in the list:

Consider the following file paths:

files:

- "{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.yml"
- "{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"

Ansible will first look in current role for:

"{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.yml"

If not found, then it will look for the file in the parent roles. And when it's not found there, then it will look for the next listed item:

"{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"

First in the current role and then in the parents.

When the actual role doesn't have a major_version yml task/vars definition and a parent role does, Ansible will open the parent one and skip any defined non-major_version of the current role.

The solution is to specify that Ansible will only look in the actual (current) role, by specifying the {{role_path}} in the vars / tasks paths. The main.yml as described in the question becomes:

```
---
- name: gather os specific variables
  ansible.builtin.include_vars: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.first_found', params) }}"
  vars:
    params:
      files:
        - "{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.yml"
        - "{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
      paths:
        - '{{role_path}}/vars'

- name: include os specific tasks
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.first_found', params) }}"
  vars:
    params:
      files:      
        - "{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.yml"
        - "{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
      paths:
        - '{{role_path}}/tasks'
```